Geth Node Always Returns Genesis Block (0x0) Despite Being Fully Synced
I am currently running an Ethereum full node using Geth, and I'm encountering a perplexing issue. Despite my node indicating that it is fully synced when using the geth attach console, API calls via curl and Postman constantly return the genesis block (0x0) when querying the latest block number.
Environment:

Geth Version: Geth/v1.13.14-stable (as indicated in the geth attach console)

OS: Windows (Geth Data Dir is on an external SSD NVME)

Command Used to Start Geth:
geth --mainnet --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin,web3 --authrpc.jwtsecret="E:\ethereum\jwt.hex" --datadir=E:\Ethereum\execution

Command Used to Start Prysm:
prysm.bat beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --mainnet --jwt-secret="E:\ethereum\jwt.hex" --checkpoint-sync-url=https://beaconstate.info --genesis-beacon-api-url=https://beaconstate.info --datadir=E:\Ethereum\consensus




Details:

When I execute the JSON-RPC call to get the highest block number using the following curl command:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_blockNumber\",\"params\":[],\"id\":1}" http://localhost:8545
I consistently receive:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x0"}

Similarly, testing with Postman gives the same result.

Direct interaction via geth attach http://localhost:8545 shows the node as fully synced, displaying current block heights significantly higher than 0.

eth.syncing command returns false, indicating the node is not currently syncing because it is fully caught up with the network.


Attempts to Resolve:

Verification of Node Sync Status: Checked multiple times, each indicating full sync.

Configuration Checks: Reviewed and ensured all configurations are correct and network accessible.

Restart and Reconfiguration: Restarted Geth multiple times with adjusted configurations to enhance logging and check operational status.

Alternative Testing Methods: Used both curl and Postman to verify the issue, ensuring no client-side anomalies.


enter image description here

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
